# Adjust widget's position and width in qtreewidget

Tags: c++, qt

I created a **Qtreewidget** which has a **Qtreewidgetitem** is a **widget** (combobox, edit box and so on).

For example, this is one part of my **code.cpp**:

```
m_pPropertyTree = new QTreeWidget();
m_pPropertyTree->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
m_pPropertyTree->setColumnCount(2);
m_pPropertyTree->setColumnWidth(0, 155);
m_pPropertyTree->setStyleSheet("QTreeView::item { height: 20px;}");
m_pPropertyTree->setHeaderLabels(QStringList() << "Property" << "Value");
...
QTreeWidgetItem *pButtonItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(m_pPropertyTree);
pButtonItem->setText(0, "Button");
//caption
QTreeWidgetItem *pCaptionItem = new QTreeWidgetItem();
pCaptionItem->setText(0, "caption");
pCaptionItem->setText(1, "Button");
pButtonItem->addChild(pCaptionItem);
//style
QTreeWidgetItem *pStyleItem = new QTreeWidgetItem();
pStyleItem->setText(0, "style");
QComboBox *pCombobox = new QComboBox();
pCombobox->setFixedHeight(20);
pCombobox->addItem("normal");
pCombobox->addItem("bold");
pButtonItem->addChild(pStyleItem);
m_pPropertyTree->setItemWidget(pStyleItem, 1, pCombobox);
```

And this is what i get:

[image]

The combobox has **original size** which is the **red rectangle**. I want to adjust it's size or position to the new one, which is the **black rectangle** size. How can i do that? Thanks.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you want to achieve. Do you want to do this programmatically  or with the ui? how much space do you want to leave? Please be more clear. p.s. hacking the default looking results usually in ugly stuff..

Comment: I would insert an empty `QWidget` in the `QTreewidget` give it a horizontal layout `QHBoxLayout` add to it both an empty `Qlabel` and your needed `QCombobox`. At this point you can precisely set the ratio of the two with the layout `setColumnStretch`.

Comment: I see what you mean. It's really helpful. Moreover, is there any combobox function or QTreeWidget function can help me to archive this. If not, i will use your solution. Thanks again.